# GCP Databricks - Send logs from application jar to Cloud Logging

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, databricks, slf4j, google-cloud-logging

This is what I am trying to do

**Objective:** I have a jar file which I am installing on my cluster and then invoking as part of a job. I want to redirect logs from my application (jar) to Cloud Logging.

I have followed this [logback guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java).

Everything works fine when I run code from my local machine, I can see logs in Cloud Logging. However, as soon as I create the jar and run it on Databricks, logs are not being redirected to Cloud Logging, rather it's being captured by console only.

I think this is **what's happening**: As Apache Spark uses log4j and it gets initialized before my jar is being loaded. When my jar is being loaded by Spark, sl4j finds the log4j implementation as it finds that jar in classpath rather than taking the logback implementation.

Is there a way I can fix this issue?

**Code:**

```scala
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

object  App {

  def test_slf4j() = {
    import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}
    val logger: Logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass.getName)
    logger.info("using slf4j ")
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit ={
    test_slf4j()
  }
}
```

**loback.xml**

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <!-- Optional : filter logs at or above a level -->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <log>application.log</log> <!-- Optional : default java.log -->
        <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType> <!-- Optional : default: auto-detected, fallback: global -->
        <enhancer>com.example.logging.logback.enhancers.ExampleEnhancer</enhancer> <!-- Optional -->
        <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Since this is a specific case, I recommend that you contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub#section-1), and they can create a workaround or create a request for a feature request.